# Can't view Swift expression values in Xcode debug area

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

I am using Xcode 9.2 and see the below messages in the debug area.

> Shared Swift state for MYAPP has developed fatal errors and is being discarded.
>
> REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.

Also, expressions are not showing their values. They always show "invalid expression"

What could be the reason?

Comment: _"What could be the reason?"_ The Swift parts of lldb are incomplete and buggy. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Oh! That is not encouraging!! Any workaround?

Comment: The swift debug information has to be recreated from clang modules which the debugger has to rebuild at debug time.  This mostly works, but sometimes - usually caused by something slightly off the beaten track in the project - the environment for rebuilding these modules isn't faithfully recorded by the compiler, so the debug information can't be reconstructed.  That's the error you are seeing.  If this is in a project you don't mind putting in a bug report, please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com and we can see whether it is a known issue or something new.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will file a bug report.